# how to animate iOS AVplayerLayer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I have an animation code that works perfectly on any `UIView` but it isn't showing any results on an `AVPlayerLayer`.

```
 var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avplayer)
 let rotationAnimation = constructRotationAnimation(animationDuration: 3.0)
 playerLayer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "rotation")
 videoView.layer.add(rotationAnimation,forKey: "rotation")
```

the videoView that is a `UIView`, animates perfectly but the same animation doesn't work in `AVPlayerLayer`.

Code where the Layer is added to View

```
func addVideoPlayer(videoUrl: URL, to view: UIView) {
         self.avplayer = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)

         playerController.player = self.avplayer
         self.addChild(playerController)
         view.addSubview(playerController.view)
         playerController.view.frame = view.bounds
         playerController.showsPlaybackControls = true


        avplayer.isMuted = false
}
```

Comment: Add the code where you've added the layer to the view.

Comment: @PGDev I have added the code.